# How to deobfuscate an obfuscated javascript file like this?

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, javascript

I'm having serious problems deobfuscating a JavaScript file at work. This file is inside a web app that I was left in charge to improve it. The problem is that I can do it without having access to this file and the previous programmer that obfuscated it is not reachable.

I tried many ways of deobfuscation but none worked.

Can someone please help?
The code it's in the link bellow:

[Link for The code](http://pastebin.com/4tEiJGLU)

Comment: Did you look through [this question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/analyzing-highly-obfuscated-javascript)? While you will probably be able to reverse most of the obfuscation, editing the resulting file will still be a big headache.

Comment: The link is dead. I'm suprised people didn't ask you to include the code in the body of the question

Answer (score 24):

There are a few tools that you might try when wanting to analyze JavaScript:

- [JSDetox](http://relentless-coding.org/projects/jsdetox)
- [Malzilla](http://malzilla.sourceforge.net/)
- [JavaScript Deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/)
- [ExtractScript](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/extractscripts/)
- [JS-Beautifier](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify)
- [JS-Unpack](https://code.google.com/p/jsunpack-n/) (see also [blog](http://jsunpack.blogspot.fr/))
- [Rhino Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Debugger)
- [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)
- [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey)
- [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/)
- [JSNice](http://www.jsnice.org/)

See also a few tutorials on analyzing obfuscated JavaScript:

- [Analyzing Malicious JavaScript](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/analyzing-javascript/) by Dejan Lukan.
- [Advanced obfuscated JavaScript analysis](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Advanced+obfuscated+JavaScript+analysis/4246) by Daniel Wesemann.
- [JavaScript Obfuscation on InfoSec Handlers Diary Blog](https://isc.sans.edu/tag.html?tag=javascript&tag=obfuscation).
- JavaScript Obfuscation - Manual Armor ([part 1](http://secniche.blogspot.fr/2012/04/javascript-obfuscation-manual-armor-1.html), [part 2](http://secniche.blogspot.fr/2012/04/javascript-obfuscation-manual-armor-2.html)) by Aditya K Sood.

And, finally, a few questions that have been already answered here:

- [Analyze obfuscated JavaScript code?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/analyze-obfuscated-code)
- [Analyzing highly obfuscated JavaScript](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/analyzing-highly-obfuscated-javascript)
- [Try to deobfuscate multi layered javascript](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/try-to-deobfuscate-multi-layered-javascript)
- [What is a good tools to reverse the effects of Minify on JavaScript?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64/what-is-a-good-tools-to-reverse-the-effects-of-minify-on-javascript)
- Or, more generally, search for the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [deobfuscation](/questions/tagged/deobfuscation) tags ([link to the search](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript+deobfuscation)).

Comment: poisonJS leads to porn site and malware. DO NOT CLICK

Comment: @Han Thanks for mentioning it, I removed the link.

Comment: @perror the JSDetox link does not work, actually a lot of the links don't work. And why is v8 in this list?